# Laravel eager loading is not working in the opposite relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve the list of tokens with their user object. This works fine, but it's not what I need:

```
// list of users with their token
User::with('tokens')->get();
```

I do the following:

```
// I want to get tokens with their user
Token::with('users')->get();
```

But it returns `false`. Any idea?

**Edit:**

Token.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

User.php

```
public function token()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Token');
}
```

Comment: Please add both models - User and Token

Comment: I just added. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defined relation name is `user()` in `Token` model and you are trying to fetch a relation called `users()` with eager loading so it should be

```
Token::with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. You are completely right. But how come does it work with both `User::with('tokens')->get();` and `User::with('token')->get();`

Comment: What is the authentication system you are using ? there is a relation called `tokens()` exists in your model rather that `token()` that you have defined.

Comment: No, when I have a relation called `token()`, it works with both `::with('token')` and `::with('tokens')`

Comment: When it's `::with('tokens)'`, laravel generate this query: `select * from "oauth_access_tokens" where "oauth_access_tokens"."user_id" in (1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25) order by "created_at" desc`, but when it's `::with('token')`, laravel generates the following query: `select * from "oauth_access_tokens" where "oauth_access_tokens"."user_id" in (1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25) `

Comment: I meant that should be a relation defined in one of your model parent's or a trait you are using has this `tokens()` method, for example `sanctum` package has `HasApiTokens` trait which has `tokens()` relation so you can say `$user->tokens`.

Comment: I'm using laravel passport, but also I have my own model called `Token`

Comment: Thank you, I understood.

Comment: You are welcome, as i said there is a `public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Passport::tokenModel(), 'user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }` in `HasApiTokens` trait.